# Can Pandas Resample be used on a different set of date ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

Hi I have a question regarding a resampling in Pandas.

In my data i have a date range from 31/12/2018 to 25/3/2019 with an interval of 7 days(e.g. 31/12/2018, 7/1/2019,14,2019 etc.), I want to resample the sales corresponding to those dates to a new range of dates, say 30/4/2020 to 24/9/2020 with a 7 day interval as previously used. Is there a way to do it using pandas resample function? As shown in the picture, I want to resample the sales from the dataframe on the left and populate the dataframe on the right.
Just to be clear: the left dataframe consists of 13 rows and the right consists of 22 rows.

[image]

Comment: please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

lets try this:

```
 df=pd.date_range(start='30/4/2020', end='24/9/2020')
```

Answer (score 0):

The new data frame can be created from the old values, the 'index' is necessary because of the different length. If you wish you can apply df2.fillna(0),too.

```
df2= pd.DataFrame( {"date": pd.date_range("2020-04-30",freq="7D",periods=22), "sales":df1.sales},index=np.arange(22) )
```

Or without using 'index':

```
df2= pd.DataFrame( {"date": pd.date_range("2020-04-30",freq="7D",periods=22), "sales": np.concatenate([df1.sales.values,np.zeros(9)])})
```